# Meaning of  "envy of his brethren"

Tags: expressions

I have googled for the definition of the expression *envy of his brethren*, but didn't get more than references to the Bible. What does this expression mean?

Comment: Please can you add some context for us? What sentences have you seen this expression in?

Comment: Also, what is it in particular that you don't understand?

Comment: Voting to close, as all the words are easily looked up, and when you put them together the meaning is unambiguous.

Comment: You likely won't find it in general use because hardly anybody says "brethren" anymore.   Just means (causing jealousy) in his (brothers, close buddies, comrades, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression means that some man's brethren envies something.

> Toby's shoes were the envy of his brethren.

This means that the shoes Toby has were causing envy in his brethren.

I will assume you know what *of* and *his* mean.

Envy is an emotion similar to jealousy. So really, Toby's brethren didn't envy his shoes, but Toby for having the shoes. In other words they wanted Toby's shoes.

Brethren indicates either actual brothers, a collection of male affiliates that one is emotionally close to, or a group of people one has been pigeon-holed as being very alike to.

Answer (score 1):

*The envy of somebody* is equivalent to *the subject of envy from somebody*.
(The OED gives one meaning of the word as  "The object of envy").